# Swift Enumerations .toRaw and .fromRaw with Xcode 6.1

Tags: enums, swift, xcode6

In Xcode 6.1, the enumerations `toRaw` and `fromRaw` functions don't work anymore:

```
enum TestEnum : String {
    case A = "a"
    case B = "b"
}

if let a = TestEnum.fromRaw("a") {
    prinln(a.toRaw())
}
```

Errors:

```
'TestEnum' does not have a member named 'toRaw'
'TestEnum.Type' does not have a member named 'fromRaw'
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Create an enum from a raw using the failable initializer with `rawValue` and get the raw value using the attribute `rawValue`.

```
if let a = TestEnum(rawValue: "a") {
     println(a.rawValue)
}
```

Read [the changelog](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) for more information.

Comment: I tried to follow the link to the changelog and I got an error in my web browser saying that my session had expired.

Comment: I think that @Chris Ritter has a better answer.  To use the property: "rawValue" rather than trying to use the method "toRaw()".

Comment: ...its the same answer

Answer (score 15):

It looks as if toRaw() and fromRaw() have been replaced with rawValue in Xcode 6.1 Beta (Build 6A1030). If CardSuits was an enum and .Clubs a case, then you retrieve the raw value with:
let suit1 = CardSuits.Clubs.rawValue
The result will be '1' if .Clubs was raw value '1'
To retrieve the String from the raw value pass the raw value as a parameter of the enum like: 
let suit1 = CardSuits(rawValue:1) (this will be an optional value)
The result will be the enum value of raw value '1', in this example .Clubs

Comment: i had this issue, AND when i switched back to Xcode 6, i STILL had the errors.  however, deleting the derived data folder and recompiling fixed it.