# A Switch With A String Enum Is Not Being Recoginized

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, enums, switch-statement

I have a CIFilter I want to do some effects to. I have an enum of type String

```
enum FilterType:String{
        case Sepiatone = "CISepiatone"
        case FalseColor = "CIFalseColor"
    }
```

But if I try the below code, the enum is NOT being treated as a string

```
 private class func createFilter(inout filter:CIFilter!,filterName:FilterType)
    {
        switch filterName{
        case .Sepiatone:
            filter = CIFilter(name: filterName) //ERROR "Extra argument 'name' in call
        default:
            println("Filter name is not a match")
        }
    }
```

The error message means its not seeing my enum type as a string and as such thinks I'm using the wrong init.

Do you know what is wrong with my switch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the rawValue property to obtain the raw value from an enum:

```
filter = CIFilter(name: filterName.rawValue)
```

Just for completeness, similarly you can use an initializer to obtain an enum case from a raw value:

```
var filterType = FilterType(rawValue: "CISepiatone")
```

**Addendum**: I think you are using an unnecessary switch in your `filterName()` method. If the `FilterType` enum contains valid filters only, a variable of `FilterType` type cannot contain a value that is not one of them. So in my opinion this implementation should work:

```
private class func createFilter(inout filter:CIFilter!,filterName:FilterType)
{
    filter = CIFilter(name: filterName.rawValue)
}
```

Moreover, using a parameter as a return value is not recommended, unless you have a good reason for that - you can just let the function return the filter:

```
func createFilter(filterName:FilterType) -> CIFilter
{
    return CIFilter(name: filterName.rawValue)
}
```

Last, you can just get rid of that function and add a `CIImage` extension:

```
extension CIFilter {
    convenience init (filterType: FilterType) {
        self.init(name: filterType.rawValue)
    }
}

let filterType = FilterType.FalseColor
let filter = CIFilter(filterType: filterType)
```

Isn't it just simpler?

---

**NOTE**: if you are, like me, are using Xcode 6.0.x, replace `filterName.rawValue` with `filterName.toRaw()` and `FilterType(rawValue: filterName)` with `FilterType.fromRaw(filterName)`.

Comment: Side note: In Xcode 6.1, `toRaw()` and `fromRaw()` have been replaced by a property and a constructor, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919075/swift-enumerations-toraw-and-fromraw-with-xcode-6-1.

Comment: I'm still using 6.0.1 - but thanks for that, I'm updating my answer accordingly

Comment: Great answer thank you. Regarding the return type, yes I normally do that. However I have created a set of classes called 'processors', and their job it take an object and mutate it. So to me it seems logical that I pass it an image, and the processor mutates it. Or would you suggest otherwise?

Comment: No, I don't have any suggestion, without a proper understanding of what your processors do. But that looks like a good reason for having a method with that signature.

Comment: I love how helpful the Stack community is! Make every answer count, I love it!