# How to get raw value in enum?

Tags: swift

I have an enum like this one:

```
enum dayofweeks:Int { Mon = 1, Tu, We, Th,Fr, Sa, Su }
```

how to can get raw value of `Sa` ?

I only know the opposite way:

```
dayofweeks.Int(RawValue, 6) = Sa
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919075/swift-enumerations-toraw-and-fromraw-with-xcode-6-1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get enum from raw value in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184795/how-to-get-enum-from-raw-value-in-swift)

Comment: @PremaJanoti Nope. None of the answers to that other question actually gives the answer to this question.

Comment: With respect to the answer below, Swift conventions on capitalisation suggest the declaration should be `enum DayOfWeeks:Int { case mon = 1, tu, we, th, fr, sa, su }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Enumerations .toRaw and .fromRaw with Xcode 6.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919075/swift-enumerations-toraw-and-fromraw-with-xcode-6-1)

Answer (score 6):

Here:

```
dayofweeks.Sa.rawValue
```

Also, why is your capitalization is reversed? **Type name should begin with Capital letter, not case name.**

And you forgot `case` keyword in `enum` declaration.

Comment: Que!?  dayofweeks.rawValue for which day?

Comment: @ElTomato, oops. Capitalization tricked me into believing `dayofweeks` was case.