# Swift 4 toRaw() update?

Tags: swift, multiplayer, swift4

I'm following a tutorial where I'm suposed to be able to write:

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState)
{
    let UserInfo = ["peerID":peerID,"state":state.toRaw()]

}
```

Maybe I'm supposed to write RawValue? Has there been an update because the videos I'm following is 2 years old.

Best regards,

Simon

Comment: Correct, `toRaw()` have been replaced by `rawValue`

Comment: It hasn't been `toRaw()` [for a long time](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/419ba5cbeaf4771fbdab2e9098c3dbe9c03e60ea)... I would suggest you find a more up-to-date tutorial ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Enumerations .toRaw and .fromRaw with Xcode 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919075/swift-enumerations-toraw-and-fromraw-with-xcode-6-1)

Answer (score 0):

The **toRaw()** method has been deprecated and replaced by **rawValue**.